# SKAction followPath end to end action

Tags: sprite-kit, skaction

I'm trying to use SKAction followPath with a given path, I noticed that the two methods available both take a duration.

```
    [SKAction followPath:<#(CGPathRef)#> asOffset:<#(BOOL)#> orientToPath:<#(BOOL)#> duration:<#(NSTimeInterval)#>]
    [SKAction followPath:<#(CGPathRef)#> duration:<#(NSTimeInterval)#>]
```

How can I get the action to stop only when it has reached the last point on the path?

Answer (score 0):

Both actions stop at the last point. Duration is how long it takes the node to get to the last path point.